# Should I convert my action method to async action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, iis-7.5

I have a web site where user can upload a PDF and convert it to WORD doc.

It works nice but sometimes (5-6 times per hour) the users have to wait more than usual for the conversion to take place....

I use ASP.NET MVC and the flow is:
- USER **uploads** file -> get the stream and **convert** it to word -> **save** word file as a temp file -> **return** the user the url

I am not sure if I have to convert this flow to [asynchronous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx)? Basically, my flow is sequential now BUT I have about 3-5 requests per second and CPU is dual core and 4 GB Ram.

And as I know `maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU is 5000`; also `The default value of Threads Per Processor Limit is 25`; so these default settings should be more than fine, right?

Then why still my web app has "waitings" some times? Are there any IIS settings I need to modify from default to anything else or I should just go and make my sync method for conversion to be async?

Ps: The conversion itself is taking between 1 seconds to 40-50 seconds depending on the pdf file size.

**UPDATE**: Basically what it's not very clear for me is: if a user uploads a file and the conversion is long shouldn't only current request "suffer" because of this? Because the next request is independent, make another CPU call and different thread so should be no wait here, isn't it?

Comment: Is the conversion CPU bound? If yes, async does not help.

Comment: Is CPU for conversion and I/O for writing the result to a file...

Comment: But the writing does not take particularly long?

Comment: writing is really quick, for instance conversion was 36 seconds and writing 0s.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that must be defined clearly here. Async(hronous) method and flow are not the same thing at least as far as I can understand.

An asynchronous method (using Task, usually also leveraging the async/await keywords) will work in the following way:

1. The execution starts on thread t1 until it reaches an await
2. The (potentially) long operation will not take place on thread t1 - sometimes not even on an app thread at all, leveraging IOCP (I/O completion ports).
3. Thread t1 is free and released back to the thread pool and is ready to service other requests if needed
4. When the (potentially) long operation returns a thread is taken from the thread pool (could even be the same t1 or, most probably, another one) and the rest of the code execution resumes from the last await encountered
5. The rest of the code executes

There's a couple of things to note here:

a. The client is blocked during the whole process. The eventual switching of threads and so on happens only on the server
b. This approach is mainly designed to alleviate an unwanted condition called 'thread starvation'. It is not meant to speed up the total client waiting time and it usually doesn't speed up the process.

As far as I understand an asynchronous flow would mean, at least in this case, that after the user's request of converting the document, the client (i.e. the client's browser) would quickly receive a response in which (s)he is informed that this potentially long process has started on the server, the user should be patient and this current response page might provide progress feedback.

---

In your case I recommend the second approach because the first approach would not help at all.

Of course this will not be easy. You need to emulate a queue, you need to have a processing agent and an eviction policy (most probably enforce by the same agent if you don't want a second agent).

This would work along the following lines:

a. The end user submits a file, the web server receives it
b. The web server places it in the queue and receives a job number
c. The web server returns the user a response with the job number (let's say an HTML page with a polling mechanism that would periodically receive progress from the server)
d. The agent would start processing the document when it gets the chance (i.e. finishes other work) and update its status in a common place for the web server to pick this information
e. The web server would receive calls from the HTML response asking for the status of the job and would find out that the job is complete and offer a download link or start downloading it directly.

This can be refined in some ways:

1. instead of the client polling the server, [websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or long polling (for example [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) covers both) could be used
2. many processing agents could be used instead of one if the hardware configuration makes sense

---

The queue can be implemented with a simple RDBMS, Remus Rușanu has [a nice article about this](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/).